# MobaXterm keepalive change default of 60s to 10s

Tags: mobaxterm

I had to change from Fiber to LTE. Now my SSH keeps timing out.

I can enable keepalive under Settings->Configuration->SSH->Keepalive, however this always sets it at 60s. 10s seems to work better for me.

I can set the keep alive in the PuTTY config menu by Ctrl+Right Clicking on the prompt and going to Change Terminal Settings...->Connection.

I unfortunately have to do this every time I start MobaXterm.

The default MobaXterm.ini file unfortunately does not have the option to change the default keepalive timeout from 60 to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found the solution after emailing them. I had to add this to MobaXterm.ini (while MobaXterm is closed)

```
[MottyOptions]
PingInterval=0
PingIntervalSecs=10
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.